# Type checks not working in a create-react-app typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have created a new react project using the command `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. Then introduced some type errors but `yarn build` is not catching those.

The changes i made are

1. Create a new file `test.tsx` under the `src` directory with following contents

```
type Props = {
  message: string
}

export function getValue(props: Props): string {
  return props.message1
}
```

2. Call the above function from index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {getValue} from "./test"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();

console.log(getValue({message: "test"}))
```

3. Run `yarn build`, its not throwing any typescript errors

Github repo - https://github.com/kanagarajkm/my-app-ts

Any help here is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The file should be `.tsx`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković this was a mistake while typing. The actual file name is `test.tsx`. you can check it here https://github.com/kanagarajkm/my-app-ts/blob/main/src/test.tsx

Answer (score 6):

Create-react-app's `typescript` template uses typescript for typecheking only. You can see typescript errors in your IDE (if it supports typescript language server) while developing application. Or running `tsc` directly from command line.

`build` script uses `babel-loader` with `preset-typescript` for [transpiling only](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#caveats). It means if typescript code is syntactically correct (but can fail type checking) it will be transpiled into `.js` files regardles of any typescript errors.

If you want to build your bundle only after it successfully typechecks you may modify `package.json` build command for `react-scripts build` to run after `tsc` finished without errors:

```json
...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "build": "tsc && react-scripts build",
        ...
    },
...
```